# (ggplot) geom_boxplots. I'd like to have means instead of medians + confidence interval for each boxplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have an issue here. Hope someone will help me out.

So by the statement

```
ggplot(data = data_control_molten_BBT, aes(x=valuesTest, y=value)) +geom_boxplot(aes(fill=dom))
```

I have created the following plot:

[x-axis: "before" and "after" treatment of two groups of patients; y-axis are the values of the test[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xx2iv.jpg)

[image]

Now, I see medians but I want to illustrate rather means (point with a number) + confidence intervals for each box.

I have tried to add the specification of "middle" in there

```
...+ geom_boxplot(aes(fill=dom, middle=mean(value))
```

but nothing has changed

Answer (score 0):

You could add a geom_point for mean, eg:
geom_point(stat = "summary", fun.y = "mean", color = "red")